# Consulta preparada y Array

Tags: php, pdo

he hecho un `CRUD` de personas con consultas preparadas en `PDO` que funcionaba y ahora me han mandado hacerlo de una manera que no entiendo, que es pasando los valores a usar en un `array` en el `execute()`.
Por ejemplo, para crear una persona puse esto y me funcionaba:

```
$stmt=conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO persona (codigo,nombre) VALUES (:codigo,:nombre)");
$stmt->bindParam(':codigo',$codigo);
$stmt->bindParam(':nombre',$nombre);
$codigo=$_GET['codigo'];
$nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
$stmt->execute();
$texto="Persona creada!";
```

Ahora he buscado por internet y he escrito esto:

```
$stmt=conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO persona (codigo,nombre) VALUES (:codigo,:nombre)");
$stmt->execute(array(':codigo'->$codigo,':nombre'=>$nombre));
```

Y me dice:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ad\personas\nuevo.php on line 59
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Como no me funcionaba, he escrito esto:

```
$stmt=conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO persona (codigo,nombre) VALUES (:codigo,:nombre)");
$persona=new Persona($codigo,$nombre);
$stmt->execute((array)$persona);
```

Y me sale el siguiente fallo:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'codigo'
>   cannot be null
>   Mi clase Persona es esta:

```
class Persona{
        private $codigo;
        private $nombre;
        function __construct($codigo,$nombre){
            $this->codigo=$codigo;
            $this->nombre=$nombre;
        }
        function getCodigo(){
            return $this->$codigo;
        }
        function setCodigo($codigo){
            $this->codigo=$codigo;
        }
        function getNombre(){
            return $this->$nombre;
        }
        function setNombre($nombre){
            $this->nombre=$nombre;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Efectivamente tú puedes pasar en el execute los parámetros y los datos. La forma correcta es la penúltima que muestras. Aunque el mensaje de error no coincide : dice que estás intentando pasar un parámetro llamado `:number` el cual no existe en la consulta preparada ni en el array del execute. ¿Ese es realmente el código? Por supuesto, cuando pasas los parámetros en el execute no los pasas en el bindParam.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la construcción de su clase Persona ? , para el tercer caso puede que esté ahí su problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El la segunda opción el `array` está mal construido , la **->** se usa para hacer referencia a métodos o atributos de una clase, lo correcto es **=>** por lo cuál estás pasando número incorrecto de parámetros

```
$stmt->execute(array(':codigo'->$codigo,':nombre'=>$nombre));
// por
$stmt->execute(array(':codigo'=>$codigo,':nombre'=>$nombre));
```

Para el último caso, según sus comentarios el error está en el nombre de del constructor , lo correcto es `__construct`, además de colocar sus campos como privados.

```
private $codigo; 
private $nombre; 

function __construct($codigo,$nombre){ 
    $this->codigo= $codigo; 
    $this->nombre= $nombre; 
}
```

**Edit**

Cómo es recomendable emplear los atributos privados de su clase, al convertir en `array` dicho objeto tendrá como claves el nombre de los atributos además del nombre de la clase por lo cuál no le estaría pasando ningún parámetro a su ejecución de la query *(ejm)*

```
( [codigo:Persona:private] => 12365 [nombre:Persona:private] => Stack)
```

La solución sería modificar a `public` cada atributo pero no sería correcto. quizá pueda crear un método dentro de la clase persona que retorne dicho `array` para ser insertado o utilizado desde otra parte de su código

**Persona.php**

```
function getArrayData(){
        return array('nombre'=> $this->nombre , 'codigo' => $this->codigo);
}
```

Para luego  llamar a

```
$stmt->execute($persona->getArrayData());
```

Comment: Bien visto. Se me escapó ese pequeño detalle.

Comment: Muchas gracias Joel, yo pensaba que era la flecha de mysql. Y si quisiera hacerlo con una clase persona?Sería de la siguiente manera?: $persona=new Persona($codigo,$nombre);
$stmt->execute((array)$persona);

Comment: Mi clase persona es así:Mi clase persona la tengo así:                                                                 
class Persona{
 public $codigo;
 public $nombre;
 function construct($codigo,$nombre){
  $this->codigo=$codigo;
  $this->nombre=$nombre;
 }
 function getCodigo(){
  return $this->$codigo;
 }
 function setCodigo($codigo){
  $this->codigo=$codigo;
 }
 function getNombre(){
  return $this->$nombre;
 }
 function setNombre($nombre){
  $this->nombre=$nombre;
 }
}

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla ese código debería haber ido en su pregunta y le daba una solución antes. Actualizaré mi respuesta

Comment: He puesto doble barra baja en el constructor y sus parametros privados, he escrito esto:                                                                              $persona=new Persona($codigo,$nombre);
$stmt->execute((array)$persona);                                                      Ahora me aparece el error:                                          SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla actualicé mi respuesta. espero le ayude. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, Dev. Joel. El método getArrayData() si me ha servido para crear bien una Persona. Ahora voy a intentar modificar el resto.